# Movie 80's/90's where humans are been replaced by cyborgs/robots

Tags: identify-this-movie

In this movie, the main character and all his relates are suppost to travel with an airplane(don't remember to where). But before the airplane take off, he had to stay, all his family die when the airplane crashes. So after a few days, all people that should be dead reappears like nothing had happened. Then all news and proves about the airplane's crash disappear, everybody starts to treat like the main character was crazy when he tries to convince them about the acident.

When he tries to prove that he is not crazy, everybody starts to chasing and try to capture him... In some point of the movie he discovers that all people from the plane were replace by cyborgs/robots and they are trying to do the same with him.

I watched this movie about 20 or 25 years ago on tv, but don't remember exactly the year. Probably is a north american movie.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Annihilator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_(film))  has many of your elements, including a plane crash, people thinking the hero is crazy and killer robots.

> An alien force planning on taking over the world causing the plane of Flight 508 to disappear and abduct the passengers and replacing them with androids. A reporter named Richard Armour who has knowledge of their existence. One of the robots is made to look like his girl friend, Angela, who was aboard Flight 508 going to Hawaii, she has returned from there, not the same person he knows along with Cindy, a friend of Angela's. Richard now becomes the hunter and hunted, knowing he must hunt down the androids.

Comment: It really does, reading all the plot from Millennium, I start to think that is not  Millennium. Annihilator seems to be the movie I'm searching for. Thanks for the answer!!

Answer (score 10):

Could be [Millennium (1989)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_(film)).

Some details match with your description, but not all of them.

> **A U.S. passenger airliner in 1989 is about to be struck from above by another airliner on a landing approach**. The pilot handles the airplane as well as he can while the flight engineer goes back to check on the passenger cabin. He comes back in the cockpit screaming, "They're dead! All of them! They're burned up!"
>
> Time travelers are visiting the present day and stealing passengers from doomed aircraft. In the future, because of pollution, the human population is no longer able to reproduce, so teams are sent in to the past to abduct groups of people who are about to die and keep them in stasis until they will be sent into the far future to repopulate the Earth. While many people in the future are in poor health, some are healthy enough to successfully pass for 20th Century humans, and are given the best of food and care so that they can successfully infiltrate, using reproductions of contemporary clothing.
>
> Every incursion into the past causes an accompanying "timequake" whose magnitude is proportional to the effects of the incursion. Each "timequake" causes physical damage in the time from which the incursion has been made. **This is why they are abducting people who will not be able to affect the future any further and replacing them with copies of those who would have died**. Thus, the flight engineer's strange comment came because all the passengers had been replaced with pre-burned duplicates in preparation for the impending crash.

Comment: Oh god! I think it is. Thanks a lot, man! I will check it out!